# Media Query construction best practices

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

What is the best approach to adding responsive media queries to a site? ...in what order and method?
Some people say mobile first is a way to go but I am wondering if the following may be a bit more easier to manage to target an average screen size (populated with all page elements, later some will be hidden on small screens such as breadcrumb links) in order to define "all" css styles, layout, typography etc. for the page so every element gets its default style. 
Then the other queries will be only defining the changes affecting each smaller size option. So the "all" block would be the largest and then all the other media queries will be just tweaks applied to override the default styles.

```
@media all { /* including all styles for all elements */ }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /* only add styles that differ from "all" and target this size changes */ }
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { /* only add styles that differ from "all" and target this size changes */ }
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { /* only add styles that differ from "all" and target this size changes */ }
@media (max-width: 767px) { /* only add styles that differ from "all" and target this size changes */ }
@media (max-width: 480px) { /* only add styles that differ from "all" and target this size changes */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

True responsive design should mean you're using as few media queries as possible.
I tend to stick to my main CSS, then a media query for tablets (780px), then a media query for smartphones (375px).